# user mapping hide password

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data

I would like to perform queries over different postgresql11-databases. Therefore I created a data wrapper and a user mapping as following:

```
CREATE server 'test' foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'name_db', host 'ip_adress');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR "Userame"
SERVER 'test' OPTIONS (user 'Username', password '******');
```

Afterwards it is possible to query with db_link left join etc.. so far no problem. My question is now, how can I hide the passwords for the different users that are visible in foreign data wrappers-postgres_fdw-'test'-user mapping-options ???

Comment: The password should only be visible to select users, I think that would be superusers, and the "Userame" himself.  Is that not good enough?

Comment: no, not good enough

Comment: Actually it's not even visible by the "Username" himself, only superuser. Good enough this time? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) file on the postgres server in the $HOME directory of the `postgres` Linux user. You can then store the password of that database user in that file.

Then you can remove the `password` option from the user mapping, as Postgres (or more precisely: libpq) will pick up the password from the password file.

Don't forget to set `password_required` to `'false'` on the user mapping unless the user mapping is for a superuser (which is an altogether awful thing to do).

Comment: The pgpass file with the different user passwords exists already on my pc (appdat\roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf)  from which I create the query. But when I create the user mapping without password and send the query I get the message: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: The password file needs to be on the **server** where Postgres is running, not on your local computer

Comment: password_required doesn't need to be false here, because the password was required and used.  It doesn't care where that password came from, as long as it was required.

Comment: @jjanes No, `password_required` needs to be set. A user mapping without password can only be used with blessing by the superuser.

Comment: I set the pgpass on server. I am superuser and when I understand it right it should be work for superusers.  What should be the code for creating the user mapping then? CREATE USER MAPPING FOR "Userame"
SERVER 'test' (user = 'username')

Comment: is the `password_required` also needed for superusers? and where/how can I set the 'password_required' only for the specific user mapping?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Right you are.  After setting it in .pgpass, I failed to unset it in the user mapping.

Comment: @oppia04  Local superuser don't need password_required, that is implicit behavior for them.  But you do have to be a superuser in order to set it for other users, they can't set it for themselves.  You would add it with `ALTER USER MAPPING FOR...OPTIONS ( password_required 'false')`

Comment: For `ALTER USER MAPPING FOR Username server test OPTIONS ( password_required 'false')` I get error message: role username don´t exist. The difference is that the username is written with initial capital letter and the error message is without capital initial letter. I tried to put 'Username' etc. but didnt work...

Comment: @oppia04: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: thank you, newbie mistake sorry. next `ERROR: invalid option "password_required".
HINT: Valid options in this context are: user, password`

Answer (score 0):

Passwords in foreign user mappings are already hidden by default, you don't need to do anything. Only superuser can see it, according to my tests.

Not even a user with a user mapping can see it.